# I need help using regex and extracting a string after a colon

Tags: regex, jscript.net

I need a little help using regex.

This is the scenario :

> function name(a :String)

or

> function name(a :String) : String

If we have the version with return type, I will need exactly the string after the colon, otherwise I would need let's say an empty string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need it for finding the return type of a function?

Comment: Yes, if there is a return type i would need it, otherwise an empty string should be fine, but not an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[a-zA-Z]*\s*\)\s*:\s*([a-zA-Z]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex may help:

```
\)\W+(\w+)
```

where `$1` will hold the value of return type

Answer (score 0):

Any word followed by : and a whitespace

```
(?<=:\s)(\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
matches = /\)\s*:\s*(\w*)/gi.exec("function name(a :String) : String");
retType = matches && matches.length>=2 ? matches[1] : "";
```